# from app import db // No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, virtualenv

maybe it looks strange, but I really don't understand what's wrong with this app.
I started learning *Flask* and in the beggining of my path I received this error.
Thanks in advance for helping! And if u can suggest pls what other databases I can use with Flask

[image: After I entered python console and tried to "from app import db"]

```
>>> from app import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Render\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

This is my structure:

`- Project(folder)`

- app.py
- database.db
- venv(folder)
- templates (folder)
- static (folder)
- **pycache** (folder)
- .idea (folder)

This is code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin
import os



PHOTO = os.path.join('static')
app = Flask(__name__) #, template_folder='templates')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = PHOTO
full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'test.jpg')

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
```

I tried import database structure from my app(flask) to the database file, I have appr. 50 links opened and didn't find anything. pip install, recreating enviroment and all these stuff

[Here is the screen with "pip list"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwnNA.png)

Comment: Flask is a third-party module.  Did you install it?  And if so, how?

Comment: I created a new "venv" for my project, activated it, then with venv I did "pip install flask". Can you tell me more about third-party modules? Cuz I'm a beginner and I don't know yet this theme. Thanks

Comment: third-party module just means it doesn't come built-in to python; you have to install it yourself.

Comment: activate your virtual env and do `pip list` then you can see all the packages that are installed. Check if flask is present.

Comment: I've checked. Yeah, it's, and all modules that I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the screenshot you might do this in Python Console?if in Python Console,it is a pure python environment, not include your app package,you need finish the code, and use `python app.py` to run it.

Comment: All processes I did with built-in PyCharm’s terminal and then used “python3” to enter the console for importing(I watched a guide on YouTube to learn how to create login/register/logout with Flask). And the guy from this video did it in this way. Maybe it’s not actual and the syntax has been changed or something else. That’s why I’m asking

Comment: alright, this is why your import failed, you need use `exit()` to exit python console, use Terminal `python3 app.py` to run it,the better way is use Pycharm to running it. maybe you left some step, or you need find other tuoral to learn this.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that, the Python interpreter was in the conda environment, and that, the conda environment wasn't activated yet.
You'll need to activate the conda environment, else libraries like Flask may fail to load.
If you receive this warning, you need to activate your environment. To do so on Windows, run: c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base in Anaconda Prompt.

You can also check: [conda.io/activation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) for more information.